# need a correct eslintrc for async/await - using 7.6+ nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, eslint

With the latest version of nodejs 7.6+ I started using async/await.

I was using jshint but from what I read they currently do support this syntax and some suggested using eslint.

So ok I set eslint up but argh.. it flags async functions too.
`Parsing error: Unexpected token init (Fatal)`

I know there is nothing wrong as my code is running fine it's just the linter.  Too if I comment out an async function it just flags the next one.  IN fact eslint only flags the first async found with this error not all of them (what up with that?)

Here is the eslintrc file made using the init wizard.  I was hoping just asking for node and es6 for env would be sufficient...apparently not.

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ]
    }
};
```

What is the fix?

I've tried several versions of .eslintrc and even saw there are a few issues related at the eslint repo but none are helping me to resolve this.  I don't think it's a bug just missing something about getting eslint set up correctly for native nodejs using commonjs (no babel).

Who knows maybe babel plugin is required to make this work even though I am not using babel???  If that's true how do I set that up.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since `async`/`await` is an ES2017 feature, you need to add that to your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    // ...
}
```