# How to use node js util.promisify with the writeFile fs function and await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

How can I convert this function to use the async/await style:

```
it.only("should bump the 'minor' version attribute", () => {
  const writeFile = util.promisify(require("fs").writeFile);
  return writeFile("bump-minor.json", "contents").then(function() {
    console.log('done');
  });
});
```

I tried using this but it doesn't work:

```
const writeFile = util.promisify(require("fs").writeFile);
await writeFile("bump-minor.json", "contents");
console.log('done');
```

It shows the following error on line 2:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token writeFile
```

If I add "async" to the mocha test function:

```
it.only("should bump the 'minor' version attribute", async () => {
  const writeFile = util.promisify(require("fs").writeFile);
  return writeFile("bump-minor.json", "contents").then(function() {
    console.log('done');
  });
});
```

Then I get this error on line 1:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
```

I'm probably missing some fundamental of how async/await and util.promisify works together in node

Using node 8.7.0.

Comment: which line?....

Comment: @FastSnail You mean the line that the error shows? I've edited the question.

Comment: @FastSnail I'm also using mocha, question edited

Comment: Could you post a complete example, including the `async` keyword?

Comment: @skirtle I have edited the question to add the node version and the async keyword in mocha's test function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running eslint before mocha in "npm test":

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "eslint *.js \"src/**/*.js\" \"test/**/*.js\" && mocha"
}
```

Removing the "eslint" call fixe the problem:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
}
```

For some reason, eslint was failing async/await syntax with mocha

Comment: You can retain the eslint check, as long as you enable ES7 in `.eslintrc`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186133/623816.